# ping command in the CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, cisco, powershell-cmdlet

In this code of block everything works great, but... when you type list it supposed to show the entire list of available servers connected, but the servers with id 02, 03, 04, 09 are not revealing, everything else it is. i tried chatgpt but she don't know the answer so i thought asking the humans here Lol.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Define an array to store the IP addresses
set "ipArray[02]=10.0.2.120"
set "ipArray[03]=10.0.3.120"
set "ipArray[04]=10.0.4.120"
set "ipArray[09]=10.0.9.120"
set "ipArray[11]=10.0.11.120"
set "ipArray[14]=10.0.14.120"
set "ipArray[16]=10.0.16.120"
set "ipArray[18]=10.0.18.120"
set "ipArray[19]=10.0.19.120"
set "ipArray[20]=10.0.20.120"
set "ipArray[21]=10.0.21.120"
set "ipArray[22]=10.0.22.120"
set "ipArray[24]=10.0.24.120"
set "ipArray[25]=10.0.25.120"
set "ipArray[26]=10.0.26.120"
set "ipArray[28]=10.0.28.120"
set "ipArray[29]=10.0.29.120"
set "ipArray[34]=10.0.34.120"
set "ipArray[38]=10.0.38.120"
set "ipArray[39]=10.0.39.120"
set "ipArray[43]=10.0.43.120"
set "ipArray[47]=10.0.47.120"
set "ipArray[49]=10.0.49.120"
set "ipArray[50]=10.0.50.120"
set "ipArray[51]=10.0.51.120"
set "ipArray[56]=10.0.56.120"


rem Define an array to store the location names
set "locationArray[02]=Bnei Brak"
set "locationArray[03]=Bilo"
set "locationArray[04]=Ashdod"
set "locationArray[09]=Talpiot Jerusalem"
set "locationArray[11]=Rishon LeZion Merkaz"
set "locationArray[14]=Netanya"
set "locationArray[16]=Eilat"
set "locationArray[18]=Segula"
set "locationArray[19]=Haifa"
set "locationArray[20]=Tel Aviv"
set "locationArray[21]=Modi'in"
set "locationArray[22]=Afula"
set "locationArray[24]=Rishon LeZion Mizrah"
set "locationArray[25]=Rishon LeZion-Designs"
set "locationArray[26]=Natzrat"
set "locationArray[28]=Givat Shaul"
set "locationArray[29]=Karmiel"
set "locationArray[34]=Zichron Yaakov"
set "locationArray[38]=Or Yehuda"
set "locationArray[39]=Netivot"
set "locationArray[43]=Beit Shemesh"
set "locationArray[47]=Rishon LeZion Mizrah"
set "locationArray[49]=Holon"
set "locationArray[50]=Yirka"
set "locationArray[51]=Kfar Qassem - lev Haaretz"
set "locationArray[56]=Yehud"

rem Count the elements in the ipArray
for /F %%i in ('set ipArray[ ^| find /c "="') do set "numLocations=%%i"

:input
rem Prompt for user input
set /p "userInput=Enter ID to ping (e.g., 56) or type 'list' for location list: "

if /I "%userInput%"=="list" (
  echo.
  echo Location Array:
  echo +-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
  echo ^| Index ^|          Code            ^|        Location          ^|
  echo +-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+

for /L %%i in (2,1,56) do (
  set "index=0%%i"
  set "index=!index:~-2!"
  set "code=!ipArray[%%i]!"
  set "location=!locationArray[%%i]!"
  set "code=!code!                          "
  set "location=!location!                          "
  set "code=!code:~0,26!"
  set "location=!location:~0,26!"
  echo ^|   !index!   ^| !code! ^| !location! ^|
)



  echo +-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
  echo.
  goto input
)






if /I "%userInput%"=="help" (
  echo.
  echo Help:
  echo This program allows you to ping IP addresses based on their ID.
  echo To ping an IP address, enter the corresponding ID.
  echo To view the list of locations, type 'list'.
  echo To exit the program, press Ctrl+C.
  echo.
  goto input
)

if not defined locationArray[%userInput%] (
  echo Invalid ID. Please try again.
  goto input
)

set "chosenID=%userInput%"
set "chosenIP=!ipArray[%chosenID%]!"
set "chosenLocation=!locationArray[%chosenID%]!"

echo.
echo Pinging IP address: !chosenIP!
set "pingResult=0"

rem Perform 5 pings for the chosen IP address
echo.
echo Ping Results:
set "pingLog="

for /L %%j in (1,1,5) do (
  ping !chosenIP! -n 1 >nul
  if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
    echo Ping attempt %%j: Success
    set "pingLog=!pingLog!Ping attempt %%j: Success`r`n"
  ) else (
    echo Ping attempt %%j: Failed
    set "pingLog=!pingLog!Ping attempt %%j: Failed`r`n"
    set "pingResult=1"
  )
)

if !pingResult! equ 0 (
  echo.
  echo Ping successful.
) else (
  echo.
  echo Ping failed.
)

echo.

rem Save the ping log to a file
set "logFile=!chosenLocation!_%chosenID%.txt"
echo !pingLog! > "%logFile%"

echo Output saved to %logFile%.

rem Define email configuration
set "from=alerts@lighting.co.il"
set "to=yuval@lighting.co.il"
set "smtpServer=mail.lighting.co.il"

rem Save the ping log with proper line breaks to a temporary file
set "tempFile=temp_!chosenLocation!_%chosenID%.txt"
echo !pingLog! > "!tempFile!"
rem Send the email using the content of the temporary file
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Send-MailMessage -From '%from%' -To '%to%' -Subject 'Ping Log - !chosenLocation! (ID: !chosenID!)' -Body (Get-Content -Path '!tempFile!' -Raw) -SmtpServer '%smtpServer%' -Attachments '!logFile!'"

rem Remove the temporary file
del "!tempFile!"

echo Email sent.

pause
```

i tried many ways of fix, i can't really remember all of them

Answer (score 0):

```
  set "index=0%%i"
  SET "index=!index:~-2!"
  FOR %%y IN (!index!) DO (
   set "code=!ipArray[%%y]!"
   set "location=!locationArray[%%y]!"
  )
```

because when `%%i` is <10, so you were looking at eg. `ipArray[3]` not `ipArray[03]`